# Increment a uint variable results in unexpected value

Tags: solidity, remix, integers

I have the function `resolveProject()` in my contract, which iterates over a list of Task, let's say 2, both with status `3`.

```
function resolveProject() {
    // ...

    uint closedTask;
    uint totalPayout;

    for(uint i=0; i<taskIds.length; i++){
        if(tasks[taskIds[i]].status == 3) {
            // Issue here
            closedTask = closedTask + 1;
            totalPayout += tasks[taskIds[i]].compensationOracle;
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

After one iteration, the line `closedTask = closedTask + 1` assign `1000000000000000000` to the variable, where my intention would be to set it to `1`. I tried also using `closedTask++` with the same result.

`1000000000000000000` gwei is `1` eth, is this some sort of implicit conversion happening? I get this when running on Remix JavaScript VM.

**Edit 1**

The Solidity code works actually fine, but I think there might be a bug in the debug panel of Remix

[image: Wrong variable value in Remix debug console]

at line 146 there is a comparison between `closedTask` and `taskIds.length`. The latter has 3 items, as you can see on the right, but `closedTask` in debug panel shows `3000000000000000000`. Still that comparison returns true when runs, I can confirm the `projectStatus` set to 2.

**Edit 2**
I created a bug in remix-ide' github, it has been tagged as bug so I assume this confirms there is a minor bug with Remix debug console.

https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide/issues/1599

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should only be adding 1. The problem is almost definitely in the method you're using to read the variable, which we can't see.

Write some tests, and if your tests fail, post the failing test.

Comment: I see the assigned value in the debug console of Remix, and I start to think that this might be an issue with Remix, because the other local variable `totalPayout` does not even appear in the Solidity Local part of debugging panel. I will try to check manually with geth and come back, good to know that you share my expected behavior for the increment.

Comment: The Solidity code works actually fine, I think this is an issue with the Remix debug console, I will update the question with more details